# Autoscaling in cosmosdb mongodb api

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, autoscaling, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

"I'm using azure cosmosdb with mongodb api and I want to know how to check whether a database in azure cosmosdb mongo api has autoscaling enabled using cosmos connection string. I'm using express.js as a middleware framework."

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to get this information is to use [`@azure/cosmos`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos) Node package.

```
import {CosmosClient} from '@azure/cosmos';

const endpoint = 'https://youraccountname.documents.azure.com';
const key = 'your account password';
const client = new CosmosClient({endpoint, key});
const databaseName = 'your database name';

const db = client.database(databaseName);
db.readOffer()
.then((response) => {
    const offerDetails = response.resource;//This will have all the necessary information.
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Here's the response for one of the databases with autoscaling throughput mode:

```
{
    "resource":"dbs/XXXXXX==/",
    "offerType":"Invalid",
    "offerResourceId":"XXXXXX==",
    "offerVersion":"V2",
    "content":{
        "offerThroughput":400,
        "offerMinimumThroughputParameters":{
            "maxThroughputEverProvisioned":4000,
            "maxConsumedStorageEverInKB":0
        },
        "offerAutopilotSettings":{
            "tier":0,
            "maximumTierThroughput":0,
            "autoUpgrade":false,
            "autoUpgradePolicy":{
                "throughputPolicy":{
                    "incrementPercent":10
                }
            },
            "maxThroughput":4000
        }
    },
    "id":"XXxX",
    "_rid":"XXxX",
    "_self":"offers/XXxX/",
    "_etag":"\"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
    "_ts":1625655292
}
```

What you would need to do is check for `offerAutopilotSettings` attribute under `content`. This will only be present if throughput mode configured for the database is 'autoscale'

Comment: Is'nt this SDK for SQL API. The npm documentation itself says that it is for SQL. Im asking for MongoAPI.

Comment: It is indeed for SQL API. For managing databases, containers, etc. you have to use SQL API. For managing data inside a container, you can use Mongo DB specific library.

Comment: That's great. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(
                            connectionString
                            (error, doc) => {
                                if (error) {
                                    return res
                                        .json({message: error})             }
                            }
                        );

connection.db.command({customAction: "GetDatabase"}) 
.then((data) => {res.json(data)})
.catch(error => {res.json(error)})

Output:
------
{
        "database" : "test",
        "provisionedThroughput" : 2000,
        "autoScaleSettings" : {
                "maxThroughput" : 20000
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-custom-commands#create-database for all other functions we can perform in comsos DB with Mongo API